# Multiple different nested objects in json to retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, nested-object

my json pic, please click [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niDqs.png)
and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Cs0G.png).  *hopefully understandable enough.*

**Story:** i want to read the Json page once. its okay, i have no problem with this.I can only read the data in the first cell. Other cells in different classes. And also i have all classes by using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
***important!!.*** Every different type, contains different named list of objects.

**But** how can i get the data in each cell to different classes by retrofit library?.

### ## featured list##

```
public class FeaturedList{
  //this my main class
@SerializedName("featured")
private List<FeaturedItem> featured;

@SerializedName("type")
private String type;

@SerializedName("title")
private String title;

public void setFeatured(List<FeaturedItem> featured){
    this.featured = featured;
}

public List<FeaturedItem> getFeatured(){
    return featured;
}

public void setType(String type){
    this.type = type;
}

public String getType(){
    return type;
}

public void setTitle(String title){
    this.title = title;
}

public String getTitle(){
    return title;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return 
        "FeaturedList{" + 
        "featured = '" + featured + '\'' + 
        ",type = '" + type + '\'' + 
        ",title = '" + title + '\'' + 
        "}";
    }
```

---

### mainActivity

```
     restInsterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(RestInsterface.class);
    Call<List<FeaturedList>> listCall;
    listCall=restInsterface.getFeaturedList();
    listCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<FeaturedList>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<FeaturedList>> call, Response<List<FeaturedList>> response) {
            for (FeaturedList item:response.body()){
                Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: "+item.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<FeaturedList>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
      }
```

---

### Logcat, Output

MainActivity: onResponse: FeaturedList{featured = '[FeaturedItem{cover = 'Cover{thumbnail = 'Thumbnail{width = '270',url = 'https://cdn.vitrinova.com/images/jewelryafile-19eff39a-e6f9-4e56-9bf1-58ee0fd7920b.jpg',height = '135'}',width = '1080',medium = 'Medium{width = '540',url = 'https://cdn.vitrinova.com/images/jewelryafile-27bc984d-08ff-43ba-9b6e-0b267ddb7c56.jpg',height = '270'}'...… --- **continue**

MainActivity: onResponse: FeaturedList{featured = 'null',type = 'new_products',title = 'En Yeni Ürünler'}

MainActivity: onResponse: FeaturedList{featured = 'null',type = 'categories',title = 'Kategoriler'}

MainActivity: onResponse: FeaturedList{featured = 'null',type = 'collections',title = 'Koleksiyonlar'}

MainActivity: onResponse: FeaturedList{featured = 'null',type = 'editor_shops',title = 'Editör Seçimi Vitrinler'}

MainActivity: onResponse: FeaturedList{featured = 'null',type = 'new_shops',title = 'En Yeni Vitrinler'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Okey I did, this is my solution. and it works.

---

```
 public class DataList{

@SerializedName("featured")
private List<FeaturedItem> featured;
@SerializedName("products")
private List<ProductsItem> products;
@SerializedName("categories")
private List<CategoriesItem> categories;
@SerializedName("collections")
private List<CollectionsItem> collections;
@SerializedName("shops")
private List<ShopsItem> shops;

@SerializedName("type")
private String type;

@SerializedName("title")
private String title;

public List<FeaturedItem> getFeatured() {
    return featured;
}

public void setFeatured(List<FeaturedItem> featured) {
    this.featured = featured;
}

public List<ProductsItem> getProducts() {
    return products;
}

public void setProducts(List<ProductsItem> products) {
    this.products = products;
}

public List<CategoriesItem> getCategories() {
    return categories;
}

public void setCategories(List<CategoriesItem> categories) {
    this.categories = categories;
}

public List<CollectionsItem> getCollections() {
    return collections;
}

public void setCollections(List<CollectionsItem> collections) {
    this.collections = collections;
}

public List<ShopsItem> getShops() {
    return shops;
}

public void setShops(List<ShopsItem> shops) {
    this.shops = shops;
}

public void setType(String type){
    this.type = type;
}

public String getType(){
    return type;
}

public void setTitle(String title){
    this.title = title;
}

public String getTitle(){
    return title;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    if(type.equals("featured")){
        return
                "Featured Olanlar{" +
                        "featured = '" + featured + '\'' +
                        ",type = '" + type + '\'' +
                        ",title = '" + title + '\'' +
                        "}";
    }
    else if(type.equals("new_products")){
        return
                "En Yeni Ürünler{" +
                        "products = '" + products + '\'' +
                        ",type = '" + type + '\'' +
                        ",title = '" + title + '\'' +
                        "}";
    }
    else if(type.equals("categories")){
        return
                "Kategoriler{" +
                        "categories = '" + categories + '\'' +
                        ",type = '" + type + '\'' +
                        ",title = '" + title + '\'' +
                        "}";
    }
    else if(type.equals("collections")){
        return
                "Koleksiyonlar{" +
                        "collections = '" + collections + '\'' +
                        ",type = '" + type + '\'' +
                        ",title = '" + title + '\'' +
                        "}";
    }
    else if(type.equals("editor_shops")){
        return
                "Editör Seçimi Vitrinler{" +
                        "shops = '" + shops + '\'' +
                        ",type = '" + type + '\'' +
                        ",title = '" + title + '\'' +
                        "}";
    }
    else if(type.equals("new_shops")){
        return
                "En Yeni Vitrinler{" +
                        "shops = '" + shops + '\'' +
                        ",type = '" + type + '\'' +
                        ",title = '" + title + '\'' +
                        "}";
    }
    return null;
    }  
        }
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Parsing for different naming of objects on the same level is possible. In one way is possible to define `@SerializedName(value="name1", alternate={"name2", "name3"}) String b;` meaning define alternate name for object. But be careful this object needs to have same data. In your case it will parse **"id"**, **"name"** in all cases since json contains those two fields in all cases.

On the other hand when you want to parse all fields is better to go with custom **JsonDeserializer**. You can find an example how to write your own deserializer for GSON library here: [Deserializer](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example/)